# Remove a column element inside an array in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Schema in PySpark and I need to remove the `item_platform_id` element from within the `items` array when it comes.
I tested using drop but it didn't work.

```
root
 |-- MISSION_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COUNTRY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSORED_MISSION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MISSION_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSORED_SEGMENTATION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- START_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- END_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSOR_PARTNER_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONSIDER_DELIVERY_WINDOW: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CONSIDER_BLOCK_LIST: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- DIGITALIZATION_LEVEL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ITEMS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_platform_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COMBOS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- comboId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ENABLED: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Expected:

```
root
 |-- MISSION_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- COUNTRY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSORED_MISSION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MISSION_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSORED_SEGMENTATION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- START_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- END_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- SPONSOR_PARTNER_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CONSIDER_DELIVERY_WINDOW: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CONSIDER_BLOCK_LIST: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- DIGITALIZATION_LEVEL: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ITEMS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- COMBOS: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- comboId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ENABLED: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: when you say `"when it comes"` what do you mean? is this data being read in live?

Comment: Sometimes this field don't coming. I need remove when it's coming.

Comment: You need to parse it and use dropFields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861603/pyspark-remove-field-in-struct-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the existence of the field within the structs of the array, and you can use [`dropFields`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html#pyspark-sql-column-dropfields) to remove the field from the struct *(available since spark 3.1.2)*.

example

```py
# sample data
data_ls = [
    (1, [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)])
]

data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data_ls, 'id int, items array<struct<_id: int, quantity: int, item_platform_id: int>>')

# +---+----------------------+
# |id |items                 |
# +---+----------------------+
# |1  |[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]|
# +---+----------------------+

# root
#  |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- items: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- _id: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- quantity: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_platform_id: integer (nullable = true)

# check existence and remove if exists
if 'item_platform_id' in data_sdf.withColumn('field', func.col('items')[0]).select('field.*').columns:
    new_data_sdf = data_sdf. \
        withColumn('items', func.transform('items', lambda x: x.dropFields('item_platform_id')))

new_data_sdf.show(truncate=False)

# +---+----------------+
# |id |items           |
# +---+----------------+
# |1  |[{1, 2}, {4, 5}]|
# +---+----------------+
```